# path to the saved pics taken in android emulator camera

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera

I am trying to create a gallery app to show only the pics taken using the camera. What is the absolute path to the pics taken using the android camera? I am using the camera in the android emulator.  My app supports API level 14+. Thank you.

Comment: "What is the absolute path to the pics taken using the android camera?" -- that will vary by camera app, device, user account, and Android OS version. And, you do not necessarily have filesystem access to this location. What you want to do is impractical IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the emulator(API 15) is saving the camera pics under the path:
"/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera".
I was able to read the pics using the following piece of code:

```
File targetDir = new File("/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera");
File[] files = targetDir.listFiles();
```